# Using $sum on a existent field returns a value of 0

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have to sum subOrderAmt on the basis of category.Below is the sample.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("589b2214a8c4d36ab9f3a7ec"),
    "_class" : "com.homeshop18.clickstream.mongo.domain.widget.Order",
    "orderId" : NumberLong(946588817),
    "subOrders" : [
        {
            "subOrderId" : NumberLong("41357348772"),
            "productId" : NumberLong(32164935),
            "subOrderAmt" : "220.00",
            "category" : NumberLong(3043),
            "isCancelled" : false
        },
        {
            "subOrderId" : NumberLong("41357348773"),
            "productId" : NumberLong(33173277),
            "subOrderAmt" : "200.00",
            "category" : NumberLong(3043),
            "isCancelled" : false
        },
        {
            "subOrderId" : NumberLong("41357348774"),
            "productId" : NumberLong(32852897),
            "subOrderAmt" : "201.00",
            "category" : NumberLong(3042),
            "isCancelled" : false
        }
    ],
    "bannerUserId" : "abdb1ec23721832dafa3e5535ff5295c75ad6f8cd2c1c91093b9ad7ff65de8ff"
}
```

sqlDB query:-
    SELECT sum(`subOrderAmt`) as totalAmt, `category` 
    FROM (`order.subOrders`) 
    GROUP BY `category

mongoDB query

> db.order.aggregate([{ $unwind : "$subOrders" },{$group: { _id: {category:"$subOrders.category"}, totalAmt:{ $sum:"$subOrders.subOrderAmt"},count:{$sum:1} }}])
>       { "_id" : { "category" : NumberLong(3042) }, "totalAmt" : 0, "count" : 1 }
>       { "_id" : { "category" : NumberLong(3043) }, "totalAmt" : 0, "count" : 8 }

Not able to get sum of subOrderAmt. Pls help.

Comment: The reason you are not getting the expected result is because `subOrderAmt` is declared as String. Use a numeric datatype.

Comment: If you use numeric data type you would get following result - { "_id" : 3042, "summation" : 201 }
    { "_id" : 3043, "summation" : 420 }

Comment: Your query would be db.order.aggregate([ {$unwind: '$subOrders'},{$group:{_id:"$subOrders.category","summation": { $sum: "$subOrders.subOrderAmt" }}}])